# htaccess - Rewrite URL to remove original filename and replace with GET value

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get, url-parameters

I'm currently using the following htaccess to remove .php extension from all files:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
DirectoryIndex start.php?
```

On my start.php page I have a GET form (action="start") for the user to select there country (start?Country=USA).

Is it possible to rewrite URLs only on the start page to show the URL as mysite.com/USA? (removing "start?Country=" but including the question mark at the end of the URL) or will this conflict with the DirectoryIndex rule?

I've tried lots of different code I've found online but none of it seems to do what I need (and usually results in internal server errors).

Cheers for any pointers =)

Comment: Is it possible to explain a little about why you want the trailing question mark?

Comment: @showdev I was intending to make the URL read like a question, eg. searchingforshoes.in/USA? (not my url)

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't think you can include a question mark in a URL like that because it is a reserved character indicating the start of a query string. You could encode it, but then it won't visually look like a question mark anymore.

Comment: Does that means the only option available is for me to have seperate files for each country name? eg. "USA.php?" could be rewritten as "/USA?" just by hiding the file extensions. This was my original plan but I assumed there would be an easier method :) Unless anyone else has any ideas? Thanks